# How do I reconstruct Image data sent from C# to a C++ dll back into an Image

Tags: c#, c++, image, dll, gdi+

I am sending image data from a C# script to a C++ dll. 
I would like to know how to turn this data back into an image on the C++ side so that it can then be displayed using GDI+.

The C# code

```
[DllImport("ExtWindow")] 
private static extern void SetImage(IntPtr img, int width, int height);
(...)
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(@"D:/my_image.png"))
        {
            BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

            SetImage(bmp.GetHbitmap(), bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            bmp.UnlockBits(data);
        }
```

The C++ code

```
Bitmap* display_img;

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) SetImage(void* data, int width, int height) {
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 24, data);

    display_img = (Bitmap*)Bitmap::FromHBITMAP(hBmp, NULL); // <=== i fail to properly convert here

    // Force WM_PAINT
    RedrawWindow(my_hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
}

(...) // A window is created earlier, which is where the image will be displayed

LRESULT CALLBACK newWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        // Display the image
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        Graphics graphics(hdc);
        graphics.DrawImage(display_img, 0, 0);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: It is a basic mismatch between parameters, often a problem with IntPtr and void*.  The C# code passes a HBITMAP handle, the C++ code can use it directly without having to call CreateBitmap().  Get ahead by changing the C++ parameter from void* to HBITMAP to make it intuitive, you don't need width and height since that's already determined by the bitmap.  And don't forget you'll have to call DeleteObject() to properly clean up.

Comment: Check to make sure the three parameter are correct in the c++ code.  The c++ may be looking for a 16 bit integer instead of 32.  Also check the size of the data to make sure it is same size in both c# and c++.